# Copy/include resource from another maven project

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, maven-resources-plugin

let me explain you what I am looking for.

There is one project whose POM.xml is at path

```
project/ui/application/pom.xml.
```

I generally build my WAR file using ui/applicatio.pom.xml.

In UI's POM I have included few modules say "applicationDTO" and whose POM is at path

```
project/common/applicationDTO/pom.xml.
```

Now in applicationDTO project there is one file `"ABC.properties"` that I want to include in the WAR file which I created using UI project.

In short, I want to include ABC.properties file in UI's project.

Below is what I have tried, But I am getting error message like

```
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Desktop\project\ui\application\common\applicationDTO\QA
```

**Note: project is source folder which is having both UI and applicationDTO project. I want file form applicationDTO folder to be copied in UI folder via POM.**

Please excuse me if I am unable to explain my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven resource plugin for this

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

You might need to adjust path's to make it work

Update :

Considering Your folder structure is

```
ABC 
-ui
  - application (build here)
    - pom.xml
    - classes
-common
  - ABC.properties
```

Now when running your maven build from application folder, below can be the section

```
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>./classes</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <includes>
                            <include>ABC.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        <directory>../../common</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@{*}</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Will it work for the property file that is placed outside {basedir}? My POM exist in "Application" folder, Which is sub folder of project UI. and I want this file to copied in classes folder of another project which is outside the reach of "Application" project basedir. Hope you got my concern?

Comment: I tried above code. But the path I have provided in output directory is skipped. <OutputDirectory>C:\Users\Gaurav\ABC\ui\application\target\Home\WEB-INF\classes</OutputDirectory> . Can I use above path as <OutputDirectory>..\ui\application\target\Home\WEB-INF\classes</OutputDirectory> Will it work?

Comment: I am sorry, If I confused you. Suppose ABC is parent folder and In ABC, UI and Common are parallel folders. In UI folder, there is subfolder named "Application" which contain POM.xml through which I build my WAR. Now I want a file from "COMMON" folder (with separate POM.xml)  which is parallel to UI folder, moved to classes of "Application" folder. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Updated my answer please check , and if application and common are independent project it should work , if they both are part of a muli-module project and which ABC is parent , you might need to add above section in parent pom.xml

Comment: Thanks man, It is now working for me. Have made some changes in root directory as well. at the end its working.

Comment: Glad it helped @G.Chahar